# Python function to strip inline repr'd unicode strings

Tags: python, strings, parsing

I have to write a python function that takes a string that contains raw unicode strings (e.g. `"u'hello' there"`) and transform it into a string that strips the `u''` identifiers from it. For example:

```
strip_inline_unicode("u'hello' there")  # -> 'hello there'
```

Without getting into too much detail as to why I have to do this, sufficed to say I cannot simply replace the logic that generates these strings, and I have to strip these because it is being returned as human-readable output to a user.

Constraints:

- Strings can have "malformed" unicode identifiers which should be handled correctly (e.g. `"hello u'there"` -> `"hello there"`)
- Strings can have empty unicode identifiers (e.g. `"hello u''there"` -> `"hello there"`)
- Strings will never have "nested" unicode identifiers (e.g. `'u"u\'foo\'"'`)
- Quotes will always be single-quotes (so never `u"<stuff>"`)

Here is what I came up with:

```
def strip_inline_unicode(stupid_string):
    """Takes a string that looks like "u'hello' there" and returns
    "hello there" """

    in_unicode = False
    pos = 0

    new_str = ''

    while (pos < len(stupid_string)):
        if pos + 1 >= len(stupid_string):
            if in_unicode and stupid_string[-1] == "'":
                new_str += stupid_string[pos:-1]
            else:
                new_str += stupid_string[pos:]
            break

        cur = stupid_string[pos]
        nxt = stupid_string[pos + 1]
        if cur == 'u' and nxt == "'" and not in_unicode:
            in_unicode = True
            pos += 1
        elif in_unicode and cur == "'":
            in_unicode = False
        else:
            new_str += cur

        pos += 1

    return new_str
```

When I plug it into the interpreter it seems to work correctly:

> ```
> In [12]: strip_inline_unicode("u'hello' there")
> Out[12]: 'hello there'
>
> In [14]: strip_inline_unicode("hello there")
> Out[14]: 'hello there'
>
> In [15]: strip_inline_unicode("hello u'there")
> Out[15]: 'hello there'    
>
> In [16]: strip_inline_unicode("hello u''there")
> Out[16]: 'hello there'
>
> In [17]: strip_inline_unicode("au'b'")
> Out[17]: 'ab'
>
> In [18]: strip_inline_unicode("u'abc'")
> Out[18]: 'abc'
> ```

However, I am by no means a Python expert, and it seems like I could accomplish something similar in a simpler and more robust manner, perhaps by using regexes. I was hoping to get some feedback on the implementation and maybe simplify it/make it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, regexps were my first thought:

```
re.sub(r"u'([^']*)'?", r'\1', string)
```

Dissected:

1. A literal `u'`.
2. Then anything that is not a `'` zero or more times: `[^']*`.
3. Store that for later retrieval: `([^']*)`.
4. End with an optional `'`.

Comment: Infinitely better. I missed the part in the `re.sub` docs that mentions that backreferences can be used to specify replacements. Really cool stuff. Thanks so much for your help!